# There's something wrong with this classification of groups of order $60$(?) How to fix it though?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Refer to: [Classifying groups of order 60](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121248/classifying-groups-of-order-60):

> **(b)** Prove that if $P\lhd G$ but $Q\not\lhd G$ then $G\cong A_4\times\Bbb Z_5$. [Show in this case that $P\leq Z(G)$, $G/P\cong A_4$, a Sylow $2$-subgroup $T$ of $G$ is normal and $TQ\cong A_4$.]

The original post put much effort into it. But I believe there is some problem with the proof of the above. Let's say that we know $G/P\cong A_4$. The original post claimed that by applying the fourth isomorphism theorem on $G/P$, we have that a Sylow $2$-subgroup $T$ of $G$, is normal. He stated in the comment that 'If say $T_1,T_2\in Syl_2(G)$ and $T_1\neq T_2$, then $T_1P$ and $T_2P$ give two distinct subgroups of $G$ of order $20$...' Surely this isn't correct:

> $\langle(12)\rangle,\langle(13)\rangle\in Syl_2(S_3)$. Let $P=\langle(123)\rangle\lhd S_3$, but $\langle(12)\rangle P=\langle(13)\rangle P=S_3$.

But how to fix it though? I want to show that $T\lhd G$.

$G/P\cong A_4$ has a unique Sylow $2$-subgroup. Let's call it $K/P$. We have $K/P\lhd G/P$, so $K\lhd G$. $|K|=20$. By applying Sylow's theorem on $K$, we have $n_2(K)=1$ or $5$. I would expect that by working in $K$, we wouldn't have as many choices for $n_2$. But still I can't think of why we cannot have $n_2(K)=5$. Is there a way to see this? Or an alternative way to show that $T\lhd G$ is also appreciated.

Comment: I think at that point in the proof we already know that $P \le Z(G)$, so $TP= \cong T \times P$ has the unique Sylow $2$-subgroup $T$.

Comment: @DerekHolt and why is $TP\cong T\times P$?

Comment: Oops... I think I have it now. This uses the fact that $T\cap P=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Although I think you already know this, I post this explicitly for other people who want to know this. Thank you for your good question.

---

Suppose $T_1P = T_2P$ and let's take any $t_1 \in T_1$ and $p_1 \in P$.

Then, since $T_1P = T_2P$ so there exist $t_2 \in T_2$ and $p_2 \in P$ such that $t_1p_1 = t_2p_2$.

so, $t_1 = t_2p_2(p_1)^{-1} $. Since we already have $P \leq Z(G)$, $t_2$ and $p_2(p_1)^{-1} \in P$ are commute.

If $p_2(p_1)^{-1}$ has order $5$, then $t_1=t_2p_2(p_1)^{-1} \in T_1$ has order $5$ or  $10$ or $20$ since $t_2 \in T_2$ and $T_2 \cong Z_4$. This is impossible so $p_2(p_1)^{-1}$ has order $1$ ,that is $p_1=p_2$ and $t_1=t_2$.

This means $T_1 \subset T_2$. (Similarly, $T_2 \subset T_1$)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative proof.

Suppose that $T_1P = T_2P$. We show that $T_1 = T_2$. Let $f \colon G \to G$ be a map defined by $f(x) = x^5$. Since $P \leq Z(G)$, we easily see that $f(T_i P) = T_i$. Hence, the assumption $T_1 P = T_2 P$ implies that $T_1 = f(T_1 P) = f(T_2 P) = T_2$, as desired. Perhaps it is worth noting that we can apply the first isomorphism theorem for $f|_{T_i P} \colon T_i P \to T_i$.

Comment: I was stuck on this point, too. I had the same question, [on what condition $H_1 K = H_2 K$ implies $H_1 = H_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3438711/do-these-assumptions-guarantee-hk-1-neq-hk-2). When I came up with the solution above, my use of the 5th power map $f$ seemed ad-hoc to me. However, after reading related QAs, I have realized that this phenomenon occurs in some restricted situations. Thus, here I share this idea.