# Defining semidirect product and presentation when one of the groups is a product of cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, semidirect-product

I'm trying to classify the groups of a certain order and have shown that a group $G$ with that order can be expressed as the semidirect product of a normal subgroup $N$ $\cong$ $C_n$ $\times$ $C_m$ and a cyclic subgroup $H$ $\cong$ $C_p$. $n$, $m$ and $p$ are all different primes.

$φ:H→Aut(N)$ $\cong$ $Aut($$C_n$ $\times$ $C_m$$)$ $\cong$ $C_{n-1}$ $\times$ $C_{m-1}$ , by Euler's totient function.

That means I'm looking for homomorphisms $φ:$$C_p$ → $C_{n-1}$ $\times$ $C_{m-1}$. Using some properties about element orders, I defined each possibility by fixing a generator of $C_p$, so I know what each homomorphism does.

Now I have to make group presentations for each homomorphism, but I don't know how to intepret the result I got from another answer that

$G\rtimes_\phi H \;=\; \langle X, Y \mid R,\,S,\,yxy^{-1}=\phi(y)(x)\text{ for all }x\in X\text{ and }y\in Y\rangle \tag{1}$

since in this case each homomorphism gives an output belonging to $C_n$ $\times$ $C_m$ and is an element with two coordinates. I understand that $R$ and $S$ are the relations of the cyclic groups.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't get that symbol to work earlier for some reason.

Comment: If $n\neq m$, then $C_n\times C_m\cong C_{nm}$ and you have a cyclic group. If $n=m$, then your automorphism group is incorrect. You actually get $\mathsf{GL}(2,n)$.

Comment: I forgot to mention it, $n$, $m$ and $p$ are all different. But then I'd have to classify the homomorphisms from $C_p$ to $C_{nm-1}$, which is a large number. I saw a similar example with groups of order 60 that gave the automorphism group in that way: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1121248/1053569

Comment: No, you don't have to classify "homomorphisms from $C_p$ to $C_{nm-1}$, because the automorphism group of $C_{nm}$ is *still* just of order $(n-1)(m-1)$ and not cyclic. But you can understand maps from $C_p$ to $\mathrm{Aut}(C_n\times C_m)\cong\mathrm{Aut}(C_{nm})$ just by looking at what the image of generator of $C_p$ does to the generator of $C_{nm}$. What you have here is a split metacyclic group. In any case, you should edit to put **all** the important information in the body of the post, not buried in the comments.